# Closure and argument confusion

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting different results when I'm working with callback functions and closures.

The first scenario:

```
var cb = function(){
   console.log("anim done");
} 

var anim = Raphael.animation({
    transform: 't0, 100'
}, 2000, cb);

circle.animate(anim);
```

When running this, the circle in question animates, and after 2 seconds the a "anim done" message is displayed in the console.

The second scenario:

```
var cb = function(msg){
   console.log("anim done");
} 

var anim = Raphael.animation({
    transform: 't0, 100'
}, 2000, cb("test"));

circle.animate(anim);
```

This causes the callback (cb) to be executed immediately. This results in the "anim done" message to be displayed right away.

Can someone clarify what is actually happening here?

Comment: Your second scenario misses a closing brace.

Comment: It don't notice any missing braces.

Comment: I've added it now. It should give a quite substantial syntax error :-)

Comment: `()` after a function name reference always **calls** the function.

Comment: o ok, thx. I was looking for a missing brace; you meant parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provide a callback, it must be a function. `cb("test")` is not a function — it's the return value of a function. If you return something from `cb("test")` that is a function, it would work as expected.

As it is, you should do this:

```
var anim = Raphael.animation({
    transform: 't0, 100'
}, 2000, function() {
    cb("test");
});
```

This way you pass a function, and not an already-evaluated expression, to the animation.

Answer (score 1):

When you put a function name all by itself, it just evaluates to the function (a function name is essentially just a variable whose value is the function.

When you follow a function name with parentheses, it means to call the function at that time, with the given arguments. The value is what the function returns.

If you want to pass a function that will call the function, you have to wrap it in a closure, using the `function` keyword:

```
var anim = Raphael.animation({
    transform: 't0, 100'
}, 2000, function() {cb("test")});
```